# Launch app with parameters with Google Now

Tags: android, command, voice

It's possible with Google Now (with voice command) to open app with parameters?

Example:

I have an app that can controls an alarm, named "Alarmed"

Can I say:
"OK google , 'command' app" -> Then open app and pass data 'command' to the app "app".

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find out if this is possible? I'm wondering the same thing... Can we pass parameters when we start a custom voice action?

Answer (score 1):

Nope! Thats not available to all developers quite yet.

Google decides what goes in for some reason.

As you can see [here](http://insidesearch.blogspot.com/2015/01/google-app-update-get-now-cards-from.html) from google.

And [more recently](http://insidesearch.blogspot.com/2015/04/new-in-google-app-more-now-cards-from.html).